# Has "def validate" been taken out in Rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Has "def validate" been taken out in Rails 3.1?  I'm on Rails 3.1 pre and it doesn't seem to be working

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :title

  private 

  def validate
    errors.add(:description, "is too short") if (description.size < 200)
  end 
end
```

The "title" validation works but the "description" validation doesn't.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Does something like this work for you?

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :title
  validate :description_length

  def description_length
    errors.add(:description, "is too short") if (description.size < 200)
  end 
end
```

Comment: that works.  but i thought the new validations were an addition to and not a replacement for the old style validations.

Comment: This was taken almost verbatem from the rails 2.3 guides. This is the old way.

Comment: that old style was deprecated since they don't want people monkey patching the `validate` method anymore

Answer (score 2):

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :title

  private 

  validate do
    errors.add(:description, "is too short") if (description.size < 200)
  end 
end
```

Comment: seems like a new interface using a block to inject into the validate method, instead of straight up overloading it.

Answer (score 0):

For other types of validations, you can also add 'Validators' like the one listed here:

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/3_0_release_notes.html#validations

```
class TitleValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  Titles = ['Mr.', 'Mrs.', 'Dr.']
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    unless Titles.include?(value)
      record.errors[attribute] << 'must be a valid title'
    end
  end
end

class Person
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  attr_accessor :title
  validates :title, :presence => true, :title => true
end

# Or for Active Record

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, :presence => true, :title => true
end
```